# How do you implement a Form in a ListView

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new to Django, I basically have a homepage which has a search bar that is being implement using a Django Form. Additionally, in the homepage I have bootstrap card whichis being used to display data from my model.

I'm using the    def_get to render the form (since it's being used to query the DB). The form is very basic, it's just a CharField. However, when I use the  def_get to render the Form in my class based view it now doesn't retrieve any of the data that goes into the bootstrap card which is causing the card to not display.

I've tried to render both the form and data in the card by using ModelFormMixin but it seems like this hasn't solved my issue yet, not sure whether this is the way to achieve this?

Forms.py

```
from django import forms


class SearchBarForm(forms.Form):

    q = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=150, required=True)
```

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from property.models import Property
from pages.forms import SearchBarForm
from django.shortcuts import render


class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Property
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = SearchBarForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <!-- search bar -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 custom-search-bar">
            <form action="{% url 'property_for_rent' %}" method="get" id="search-form">
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6-md-4 custom-search-bar-button">
            <button type="submit" form="search-form" class="btn btn-light" value="For sale">For rent</button>
            <button form="rent" type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="For sale">For Sale</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- search bar -->

    <!-- property card -->
    <div class="row">
        {% for property in object_list|slice:"3" %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch custom-cards">
            <div class="card" style="width: auto;">
            <div class="card-img">
                {% if property.image %}
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{property.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap"> {% endif %}

            </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> {{ property.location }} </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ property.description }} </p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-{{ property.id }}">View</button>
                </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated</small>
            </div>
            </div>
     <!-- property card -->

            <!-- Full Height Modal Right -->
            <div class="modal fade right" id="modal-{{ property.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                <!-- Add class .modal-full-height and then add class .modal-right (or other classes from list above) to set a position to the modal -->
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-height modal-right" role="document">

                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">{{ property.location }}</h4>

                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>{{ property.description }}</p>
                            <ul class="list-group z-depth-0">
                                <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                                    Bedrooms
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                                    Price
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                                    Location
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">
                                    Property Type
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Full Height Modal Right -->

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What I want to achieve is to both display the search bar and the cards which are using data from my models.

Any hints on how to achieve this is much appreciated as i'm just a beginner :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass your form in the [**`get_context_data`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Property
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, *kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = SearchBarForm()
        return context
```

or you can make this more declarative, by making use of the [**`FormMixin`** mxin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class HomePageView(FormMixin, ListView):
    model = Property
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form_class = SearchBarForm
```

Comment: I opted to go for the FormMixin! That was more straight forward than what I thought! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Willem Van Onsem do you mind explaining why the data in the card wasn't displaying when I used   def_get to render the Form?

Comment: @AlvaroMarin: because a Django `ListView` implements `get(..)` itself (you can here check its implementation https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/). As you can see, it uses `get_context_data` to generate a context, and it adds the `object_list` in that context. Since you defined your own get, you thus no longer obtained that part of the context.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)